# apache ignite 1.6.0 xa resource enlist in existing jta transaction

Tags: java, transactions, jta, xa, ignite

```
 Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();

How to make this ignite instance fall into existing jta transaction..
Tried..


 TransactionConfiguration transactionConfiguration = new TransactionConfiguration();
  Factory factory = FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(userTransactionManager);
       transactionConfiguration.setTxManagerFactory(factory);
       transactionConfiguration.setUseJtaSynchronization(true);
```

How to corellate these `TransactionConfiguration` with the instance of ignite..!! Any help..! Referred .. http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/transactions#integration-with-jta ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransactionConfiguration` is the part of `IgniteConfiguration`, so you can provide it during start:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setTransactionConfiguration(transactionConfiguration);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Comment: But the data remains, in cache for the transaction rollback also.. with the above configuration...!

Comment: Can we start ignition and then add the TransactionConfiguration... to the running ignite?

Comment: @peaceUser No, this configuration is static and can't be changed after the node is started.

Comment: so what can I do if I want to enlist an xaResource of ignite to the existing jta-transaction. do I have to finish all the TransactionalConfiguration first for the ignite to start, or even after starting it, will I be able to setTxFactoryManager with an instance of UserTransactionManager..?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Once Ignite is configured with JTA integration on startup, nothing else needs to be done. Ignite will enlist into JTA/XA transaction automatically.

Comment: @peaceUser This happens automatically. If transaction manager is provided in the `IgniteConfiguration` and there is an ongoing JTA transaction, all cache operations will be enlisted in as this JTA transaction. See the example in configuration.

Comment: @Valentin True, that I have tested it, but on startup... Not after startup.. as our need is after startup, then the resource has to be enlisted.. Basically, start on init, and enlist cache when needed.. With the customized architecture which we follow, will lead, this ignite to start nodes (if configured - cluster), for each request.. to avoid this, we need to start and then have to enlist on the go for requests.(Which is possible with the hazelcast instance, where the XAResource enlist implementation is external), hence get the resource from one instance and then enlist when needed..

Comment: @peaceUser Are you saying that you don't have transaction manager when you start Ignite? What is the use case behind that? How is your application organized?

Comment: Use case is, Ignite should be started once, without transaction, if transaction is needed then enlist with the userTransaction which is already available, else just get the non transactional instance. As per the above, the instance will always be in transactional, which means we cannot control it. I hope this gives more clarity.. (Both cannot be achieved at same time). One more thing is, if we need both, twice the Ignite has to be started..:)

Comment: @peaceUser This is not correct. If there is no JTA transaction in the current thread, cache operations will not enlist as an XA resource. Actually, everything works exactly like you described in Ignite, except that it's done automatically without forcing you to enlist resources manually. The only thing you need to do is make Ignite JTA-aware by providing transaction manager. No transactions exist at this point. Make sense?

Comment: Its not at all starting transaction..!

Comment: @peaceUser JTA transaction or cache transaction? Please provide a test that doesn't work for you and I will be able to investigate.

Comment: TransactionConfiguration transactionConfiguration = new TransactionConfiguration();    
Factory factory = FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(userTransactionManager);
      transactionConfiguration.setTxManagerFactory(factory);
transactionConfiguration.setUseJtaSynchronization(true);
    
IgniteConfiguration configuration = new IgniteConfiguration();
configuration.setTransactionConfiguration(transactionConfiguration);
    Ignite igniteInstance = Ignition.start(configuration);

this is what I have tried..

Comment: One more is, TransactionConfiguration transactionConfiguration = new TransactionConfiguration();
    Factory factory = FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(userTransactionManager);
 transactionConfiguration.setTxManagerFactory(factory);  transactionConfiguration.setUseJtaSynchronization(true);   igniteInstance.configuration().setTransactionConfiguration(transactionConfiguration);

In this case assuming the Instance already exists, which is not in Transaction.

Comment: The first one works, with transaction, but I want to complete the second one, please check it out...

Comment: @peaceUser It's absolutely not clear to me what is the issue you're facing. Please provide the full example of how you start Ignite, start and commit transactions, etc. and explain what is not working for you. Also please use gist.github.com or similar tools to paste the code, it's unreadable here.

Comment: Transactional config after init of Ignite: 
https://gist.github.com/VivekParanthaman/822a36504e1a65b1ddf4eca59b16e474

Comment: @peaceUser This is not a full example. This will not work, but this configuration only makes Ignite JTA-aware. Why do you need to configure `TransactionManager` after Ignite is started? How the transaction manager is created? Give more details on the use case.

Comment: I was trying to get only one instance for one thread, which will init the ignite on startup, and hence use it for rest, where Init steps need not be a transactional based load, however after init I am making a transactional call for all other steps, hence, I need to set transaction after initialization..

Comment: In the code snippets you were providing so far you don't set a *transaction*, you set a *transaction manager*. It sounds like you're confusing these two things. Are you familiar with JTA? Typically, you will have a single instance of Ignite and a single instance of JTA transaction manager, both initialized on the application startup, and you just need link them through Ignite config. Everything else is handled automatically. If your approach is different, you have something very specific, and unfortunately I'm having hard time understanding what exactly you're trying to achieve.