# TransactionContext in hazelcast, anything like this in Ignite?

Tags: java, transactional, distributed-transactions, gridgain, ignite

"HazelCast" has `TransactionContext` , is there anything similar to the same functionality which is available in "ApacheIgnite",

What my understanding on TransactionContext is, which is a temp storage over transactional Map, or any of it.

Which will commit only, if all transaction is successful, on this particular commit.

eg: `TransactionContext context1 = xaResource.getTransactionContext();`

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether Apache Ignite has transactions, then the answer is Yes, Ignite supports ACID transactions very well.

More information on Ignite transactions here:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions

Here is a basic code example:

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();

IgniteTransactions transactions = ignite.transactions();

try (Transaction tx = transactions.txStart()) {
    Integer hello = cache.get("Hello");

    if (hello == 1)
        cache.put("Hello", 11);

    cache.put("World", 22);

    tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: not only the transactional support... the context object is a lil bit useful for xa transactions, my question is for the context @Dmitriy

Comment: not only the transactional support... the context object is a lil bit useful for xa transactions, my question is for the context, and yes I have been reading your blog about the comparison, where the missing part is Transactional context kind of thing...  @Dmitriy, and that was really nice.. http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/transaction/TransactionContext.html

Comment: What functionality do you really need that is not present in Ignite Transaction? https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.6.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/transactions/Transaction.html

Comment: 1.) we cannot enlist the xa resource of ignite, to an existing jta after starting ignite..

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions#integration-with-jta

Comment: no..this is manual commit by getting the userTransaction, enlisting for me is enlisting to the existing global xaTransaction,where it has to commit when the Global Transaction commits...

Comment: Not sure I understand. This code shows how Ignite transaction automatically enlists into XA transaction and automatically commits when XA transaction commits. In your case, if you have an XA transaction already running, Ignite will automatically enlist into it as well. If this does not answer your question, then I do not understand your use case and perhaps you should provide a coding example in your question.

Comment: That's what I want to acheive, amd the flexibility is very less, if we want the same xaResource to be enlisted, we have to configure the ignite instance in Transactional mode, and is impossible to enlist or make it XA transactional once the instance is started...!, may be the answer provides some more understnding.. .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126971/apache-ignite-1-6-0-xa-resource-enlist-in-existing-jta-transaction/38129753?noredirect=1#comment63738067_38129753

Comment: On startup, Ignite cache has to be configured as either Transactional or Atomic. If the cache is Transactional, then Ignite will automatically enlist into ongoing XA transactions. This means that if you start XA transaction, you don't need to do anything else, Ignite will automatically enlist into it. I am not sure what other behavior beyond that you would need or why. I updated the answer in the linked thread you provided as well.

Comment: @Dimitriy, just by setting the cache will not enlist to ongoing XA(have tested it), we have to configure the TransactionConfiguration, with userTransactionManager in the Factory, and then we have to start it, and I am looking for an alternative, to start initial only once, as single instance, and hence enlist then after starting..

Comment: In order to have Ignite automatically participate in XA transactions, you do need to configure it in Ignite TransactionConfgiuration. If you don't know your XA configuration in advance, you I don't think you will be able to add it later, after the cache is started.

Comment: Yes you are right, that we have to know the XA transactions in advance, so that we can configure it even before ignite starts..